# SignalR Client - IHubProxy.On<> and Invoke<> accepting an interface

Tags: c#, signalr

I am building a windows service that will act as a client to an existing site that's employing SignalR.

I have `IHubProxy.On<>` and `IHubProxy.Invoke` methods working when passing around concrete classes.

For example, this works:

```
 hubProxy.On<MigrationRequest>("iSWindowsServiceRequest", request =>
     MigrateData.Invoke(request));
```

And the MigrationRequest looks like this:

```
public class MigrationRequest : IISWindowsServiceRequest
{
    public MigrateWhat What { get; set; }
    public MigrationFor For { get; set; }
    public Guid EntityFor_Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now, If i try this:

```
hubProxy.On<IISWindowsServiceRequest>("iSWindowsServiceRequest", request => 
Handshake.HandleRequest(request));
```

my request is never picked up.

what I was hoping to achieve was creating single pub-sub methods, rather than one for each concrete class that this service would accept.

Is it possible to pass in an interface into the `On<>()` methods?

The same goes for the `Invoke<>()` - if the object I am passing contains any properties that are of an interface, the call never makes it.

so this will not work:

```
public class ISWindowsServiceResponse
{
    public IISWindowsServiceRequest OriginalRequest { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

but this will

```
public class ISWindowsServiceResponse
{
    public MigrationRequest OriginalRequest { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you only want the pub-sub you can try using PersistentConnection instead of Hubs, they are simpler but you might have to handle the serialization/deserialization yourself. That's if you can change the SignalR part.

Comment: How would SignalR deserialize json payload to an interface?  There must be an actual class implementing an interface and SignalR does not know what it is so it can instantiate. Note that interface can have multiple implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Where I work, we spent a lot of time trying to figure out a way to get SignalR hubs to serialize interfaces. In the end, we wound up having to extract real objects (real classes and structs, not behind an interface) to send over the wire. There is no way to tell SignalR how to serialize an interface.

Comment: (I would have made this a comment, but I'm not reputed enough to make one. Sorry!)